# Error in adding two polynomial using array and struct in C

Tags: c

I believe my code have a correct arthgorithm and no error when compile. However, the result of adding 2 polynomials always is 0x^0. I think the error come from the attach function. Can anyone help me check it ? 
Thank you very much

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_DEGREE 1001

typedef struct
{
    int degree;
    float coef[MAX_DEGREE];
}polynomial;

int leadExpon(polynomial poly);
void printPoly(polynomial poly);
float coef(polynomial poly, int expon);
bool IsZero(polynomial poly);
polynomial zero();
polynomial attach(polynomial poly, float coef, int expon);
polynomial Remove(polynomial poly, int expon);

int main()
{
    polynomial poly1,poly2,polySum;
    int expon1,expon2;
    printf("Enter the first polynomial:\n");
    poly1=zero();
    printf("\nEnter exponent: ");
    scanf("%d",&expon1);
    while (expon1>=0)
    {
        printf("Enter coefficient: ");
        scanf("%f",&poly1.coef[expon1]);
        printf("Enter exponent: ");
        scanf("%d",&expon1);
    }
    printf("\nThe first polynomial is:\np1(x)= ");
    printPoly(poly1);


    printf("\n\nEnter the second polynomial:\n");
    poly2=zero();
    printf("\nEnter exponent: ");
    scanf("%d",&expon2);
    while (expon2>=0)
    {
        printf("Enter coefficient: ");
        scanf("%f",&poly2.coef[expon2]);
        printf("Enter exponent: ");
        scanf("%d",&expon2);
    }
    printf("\nThe second polynomial is:\np2(x)= ");
    printPoly(poly2);

    int sum;
    polySum=zero();
    while (!IsZero(poly1)&&!IsZero(poly2))
    {
        if (leadExpon(poly1)<leadExpon(poly2))
        {
            polySum=attach(polySum,coef(poly2,leadExpon(poly2)),leadExpon(poly2));
            poly2=Remove(poly2,leadExpon(poly2));
        }
        else if (leadExpon(poly1)==leadExpon(poly2))
        {
            sum=coef(poly1,leadExpon(poly1))+coef(poly2,leadExpon(poly2));
            if (sum!=0)
            {
                polySum=attach(polySum,sum,leadExpon(poly1));
                poly1=Remove(poly1,leadExpon(poly1));
                poly2=Remove(poly2,leadExpon(poly2));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            polySum=attach(polySum,coef(poly1,leadExpon(poly1)),leadExpon(poly1));
            poly1=Remove(poly1,leadExpon(poly1));
        }
    }
    printf("\nSum of two polynomials is:\np1(x)+p2(x)= ");
    printPoly(polySum);
    return 0;
}

int leadExpon(polynomial poly)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<MAX_DEGREE;i++)
    {
        if (poly.coef[i]!=0)
            poly.degree=i;
    }
    return poly.degree;
}

void printPoly(polynomial poly)
{
    int expon;
    poly.degree=leadExpon(poly);
    printf("%.2f",poly.coef[poly.degree]);
    printf("x^");
    printf("%d",poly.degree);
    for (expon=(poly.degree-1);expon>=0;expon--)
    {
        if(poly.coef[expon]!=0)
        {
            if(poly.coef[expon]>0)
            {
                printf(" +");
                printf("%.2f",poly.coef[expon]);
                printf("x^");
                printf("%d ",expon);
            }
            else
            {
                printf(" ");
                printf("%.2f",poly.coef[expon]);
                printf("x^");
                printf("%d ",expon);
            }
        }
    }
}

float coef(polynomial poly, int expon)
{
    if (poly.coef[expon]!=0)
        return poly.coef[expon];
    else
        return 0;
}

bool IsZero(polynomial poly)
{
    int expon;
    int count=0;
    for (expon=0;expon<MAX_DEGREE;expon++)
    {
        if (poly.coef[expon]==0)
            count++;
    }
    if (count!=MAX_DEGREE)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

polynomial zero()
{
    int expon;
    polynomial poly;
    for (expon=0;expon<MAX_DEGREE;expon++)
    {
        poly.coef[expon]=0;
    }
    return poly;
}

polynomial attach(polynomial poly, float coef, int expon)
{
    if (poly.coef[expon]!=0)
        poly.coef[expon]=coef;
    return poly;
}

polynomial Remove(polynomial poly, int expon)
{
    if (poly.coef[expon]!=0)
        poly.coef[expon]=0;
    return poly;
}
```

Comment: SO is no code review site. Use a debugger and provide a **[mcve]** long with a **specific** problem statement..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this post on [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  It should give you some good ideas on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Suggest stepping through the code with a debugger, like gdb, while keeping track of the contents of the coef[] array and the value of degree for each polynomial array.

Comment: suggest checking the value read in for expon[1|2] to assure it is in the valid range 0...1000.    suggest extracting the logic to enter a polynomial into a separate sub function, so the code does not need to be repeated.    the printPoly() function has a logic problem because it only prints the first 'degree' entries and the data might not even be in the first 'degree' entries.  Suggest loop through all the entries (1001 entries), check if entry contains data and if so, then print that entry,   This should eliminate the need for the 'degree' field and related processing

Comment: The problem may come from the function `attach()`. In this function, the coefficient is set if and only if its value is already not 0. Since the coefficient are initialized to 0, values never change...and you get a null polynom in the end ! Could you try to remove `if (poly.coef[expon]!=0)` in function `attach()` ?